# Find path of a PID process

Tags: powershell, pid

I want to get the path of a PID. For example the PID is 8036, I want to get the path of it. Like this:

```
Get-Path -pid 8036

Output:
C:\Windows\svchost.exe
```

How can I do that? Or can I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```ps
Get-Process -Id 8036 -FileVersionInfo | Select FileName
```